# What should I do to speed up my vue.js project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, frontend

When my web application is loading for the first time on a browser it takes from 15 to 20 seconds to finish loading.

Here is My web application speed test on page speed insights.

[image: My web application speed test on page speed insights]

1. I removed as much unused JavaScript and redundant code as I could
2. For text compression problem my application is already generating gzipped .js and .css files according to build results (Please correct me if i am wrong in this point)
   [image]

**Do I need to setup webpack in my application or my application is already doing everything it does**

Comment: I would suggest Nuxt. SSR is almost always faster.

Comment: I appreciate the effort that you put in to posting this, but realistically it's not possible for us to answer it. We'd need to do a dive into your codebase, and that's more in the realm of "consulting contract" than "stack overflow q&a".

Comment: @Erenn is there any way I can speed up the application without using Nuxt ?

Comment: @JaredSmith I agree with you but the thing I don't know what part to share from my codebase (it is huge) and I think it will be very confusing for anyone trying to help so I thought if anyone need more specific resources I would provide them

Comment: Have a google of reduce vue js bundle size - there's a few articles out there that might give you some ideas

Comment: Is it possible for you to switch to Vite?

Comment: @MarwaAbdElBasit that's what I'm saying: there's no way you could ever post enough of this for us to be able to see what's going on, and there's no way the answer would fit in the format of a stack overflow answer. This just isn't the right venue for that sort of thing. The best we could possibly do is offer generic advice like "switch to SSR", which is why that's what you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding couple of points you can try it, it might helpful.

1. Virtual Scrolling - Use virtual scrolling it only renders required data, it will increase your perfomance.
2. Render Once - This keyword is from vue js documentation , v-once -> You can use this keyword where element should always rendered once.

   ```
    Ex: <span v-once>test</span>
   ```
3. Eliminate Duplicate Rendering - This point will also help in perfomance.
4. Remove unused packages and components.

Comment: thank you very much for you answer
actually, I have been trying to use Virtual Scrolling and found this https://github.com/tangbc/vue-virtual-scroll-list
But can you help me how to use with tables ??

Comment: I haven't used in vue js, but this will help you - https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-virtual-scroller-table-forked-orlf2e?file=/src/common.js and if you like my answer point do upvote and accept :).